# Sorting depending on two columns and assigning values to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a dataframe as `df` (created using pandas module):

```
     ID   Distance
 0   105   86.7
 1   105   60.5
 2   106   48.3
 3   106   14.1
 4   106   37.2
 5   106   30.8
```

And I am trying to create a column (`"Score"`) that represents the scores of minimum distances based on the same `"ID"`.

In other words, for the objects have the same `"ID"`, following rules are applied;

If the object has the minimum distance, `"Score"` will get the value "4".

If the object has 2nd minimum distance, `"Score"` will get the value "2".

If the object has 3rd minimum distance, `"Score"` will get the value "1".

If the object has 4th and n'th. minimum distance, `"Score"` will get the value "0".

Here is my expected `Out_df`:

```
     ID   Distance  Score
 0   105   86.7     2
 1   105   60.5     4
 2   106   48.3     0
 3   106   14.1     4
 4   106   37.2     1
 5   106   30.8     2
```

I need help for sorting issue.

Comment: I need to sort the distance by grouping the sub - ID s. for example, for the ID==105, there are two rows. And the second one has the minimum value. so 4 is assigned to second row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

1. [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to get sub DataFrames for each `ID`
2. [`nsmallest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nsmallest.html) to identify these threshold elements.
3. [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) to take each of these sub DataFrames and get scores.

Code:

```
def my_sort(s):
    d = dict(zip(s.nsmallest(3), [4, 2, 1]))
    return [d.get(v, 0) for v in s]

df['Score'] = df.groupby('ID').transform(my_sort)
```

Checkout the [pandas groupby docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) for useful `groupby` idioms.